# How to display a specific text with the same first slug in two different pages?

Tags: wordpress, slug

I have some pages with two slugs,

For the first one they have both property,

For the last one it could be status or features .

Something like :
http://www.mywebadress.com/property/status
http://www.mywebadress.com/property/features

I want to display "Text 1" if i'm on the status page and "Text 2" if i'm on the features page. How can i do it ?

I've to use a slug function of wordpress like this code but for slugs ?

Thanks

```
    <?php
    if(is_page()){

    echo 'Text 1';

    } elseif(is_page()){

    echo 'Text 2';

    } else {

      //// 

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just create subpages. This will give you the slug system you want and it will be easier to manage each page individually. The codex has information on how to do this here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#To_create_a_subpage